# Executing all files inside a folder in Python

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, shell

I have 20 Python files which is stored inside a directory in ubuntu 14.04 like 1.py, 2.py, 3.py , 4.py soon

i have execute these files by "python 1.py", "python 2.py" soon for 20 times.

is their a way to execute all python files inside a folder by single command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.py" -exec  python3 {} \;
```

Comment: This will eventually recurse in subdirectories, which might not be what the OP wants.

Comment: Added `maxdepth 1`

Comment: use python instead python3 for less than Python 2.7

Comment: @RedEyed: Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

```
for F in $(/bin/ls *.py); do ./$F; done
```

You can use any bash construct directly from the command line, like this for loop.  I also force `/bin/ls` to make sure to bypass any alias you might have set.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop inside the folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
for script in $(ls); do
    python $script
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the library glob.

First install the glob lybrary.

Then import it:

```
import glob
```

Then use a for loop to iterate through all files:

```
for fileName in glob.glob('*.py'):
    #do something, for example var1 = filename
```

The * is used to open them all.

More information here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html